# Bootstrap Accordion open on target link AND only one active

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So using wordpress I created a menu with products that have a 3 level dropdown. Basically if you click on a link of a 3rd level nav, it will take you to the parent nav of that link, which contains an accordion. I got the first part working where when you click on the link, it will take you to the page and then open up the accordion associated with that target id like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function( $ ) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var anchor = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
        $(".collapse").collapse('hide');
        $("#" + anchor).collapse('show');
    });
})( jQuery );
</script>
```

However, when i go back to the menu, all links that are targets on this page are now active. I need help on adding something to the script above that checks to make sure only the clicked link is active. For example:

```
<li class="dropdown menu-products"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="http://mywebsite/products/">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu menu-electronics"><a href="http://mywebsites/product_type/electronics/">Electronics</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="menu-tv"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse414">Tvs</a></li>
        <li class="menu-phones"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse416">Phone</a></li>
        <li class="menu-games"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse418">Games</a></li>
        <li class="menu-other"><a href="/product_type/electronics/#collapse420">Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is what wordpress generated for me. if I go to lets say "/product_type/electronics/#collapse414" it does work and open but all links that are under that electronics page are active. So, if I go back to the nav and try to click on another product that's now active it will not work. The link on top changes but it will not open that new accordion selected unless it's target is on a different page.